# Carregar url de imagem - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que carrega quando clicamos no próprio *input* que tem a URL da imagem:

```
<input name="miniatura" value="<?php echo $miniatura;?>" class="miniatura">
<img id="miniatura_exibe" />

//carregar url de imagem
$(document).on('click','.miniatura',function(){

      var valor = $(this).val();

      $('#miniatura_exibe').attr('src', valor);

});
```

Como faço para ao invés de exibir a imagem no clique do input, exibir no carregamento da página? Já tentei `$(document).on('ready','.miniatura',function(){` não consegui. Não sei se funciona assim.

Uso o JQuery em:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
$(function(){
   $("#miniatura_exibe").attr("src", $(".miniatura").val());
});
```

O `$(function(){` é o mesmo que `$(document).ready(function(){`, ou seja, quando o DOM estiver carregado.

A [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) informa que a sintaxe `$(function(){` é a recomendada a partir da versão 3.0:

> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other
>   syntaxes still work but are deprecated.

Ou seja, `$(document).ready(` (entre outras sintaxes citadas na documentação) ainda funcionam, mas estão obsoletas.

Comment: Blz. Funcionou certinho. E como faço para, se eu trocar a url da imagem no inout já carregar? Sem puxar de banco, somente trocar a url. Coisa simples. Seria change, mas aqui não rola.

Comment: Teria que fazer um change mesmo.

Comment: $(document).on('change','.miniatura',function(){ assim?

Comment: Pode ser assim para simplificar: https://jsfiddle.net/mc1keLp9/

Comment: Vc é o cara. Brigadão amigo.